# Python multiprocessing doesn't speedup statistical modeling

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, statsmodels, arima

I have defined a Python function to utilize all the CPU cores to build ARIMA (Financial Forecasting) models in parallel. The server that runs this code has 48 cores. So, I'm splitting my large Pandas dataframe into 40 partitions (to be on safer side) and process all the partitions in parallel using multiprocessing module's Pool function. The "func" is a function that returns the resultant dataframe after applying Statsmodels ARIMA on individual partitions. Although I can clearly see that multiple processes are running simultaneously in my UNIX shell, I observe no actual speedup from non-parallel processing. I guess this is due to slower inter-process communication. What can I change in my code to get higher processing speed?

```
def MultiProcessing_dataframe(df, func):
   n_Partitions = 40
   df_split   = np.array_split(df, n_Partitions)
   pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
   Results = pd.concat(pool.map(func, df_split))
   pool.close()
   pool.join()
   return Results
```

Comment: That entirely depends on `func`. Is this even a sound approach? I haven't looked at ARIMA for a while.

Comment: I was under the assumption that multiprocessing should work regardless of the underlying function since it's hardware level. What properties do you think "func" should have to be sped up by multiprocessing?

Comment: have you tried explicitly passing the number of processes you want to use to `Pool`. i.e. `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(n_Partitions)`?

Comment: What do you mean "it's hardware level"? It's creating multiple python processes. But anyway, it *is working*, it's just not faster. Parallelizing things isn't a magic bullet. It may make your code faster, it may make it slower. It is entirely up to what is actually going on in `func`.

Comment: I haven't but doesn't Pool by default set the parameter processes = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

Comment: So, for example, the ARIMA might (I don't know the implementation details here) be using some parallel algorithm already, in which case, creating a bunch more processes would gain you nothing, and could very well make it perform worse.

Comment: when the question is about time execution, you always should profile your application to understand the "slow" places. As alternative to full profiling, it is good idea to count the execution time of each process and the `MultiProcessing_dataframe` function in summary. Inter-process pipes with data pickling is not the best solution for big data sets.

Comment: Depending on the linear algebra LAPACK and BLAS libraries, the estimation might already be multiprocessing (but I'm not sure how much this happens in ARIMA). see e.g. for OLS/WLS https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3542

Comment: You've mentioned about interprocess communication. What in `func` is facilitating this interprocess communication? Do you have any shared memory? Also, be very careful about `deadlocks`. You may get some insights about deadlocks from my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53385540/how-can-i-inherit-parent-logger-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing-especially/53385789#53385789

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't know ARIMA's inner implementation details as far as multiprocessing goes. However, I suspect that it's not parallelized since only one python process is running when I run a single ARIMA process.

Comment: @PruthviKumar I don't think I'm explicitly allocating any shared resource

Comment: How many cores do you have on target machine running this code? @JimitBavishi

Comment: @JimitBavishi its not about multiprocessing. Just because you only see a single python process, that doesn't mean you aren't using parallelized code. As mentioned by Josef, `statsmodels` can be using some underlying BLAS/LAPACK library that is implemented in C/Fortran. The point is you shouldn't expect just throwing `multiprocessing` at something will necessarily give you performance improvements.

Comment: @PruthviKumar I have 48 cores on my target machine

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the clarification. I'll look into other tools like Dask to speed up my code.